# using recursion with Kivy on_complete Animation event?

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I am attempting to animate 10 widgets in sequence, each animation should start as the previous completes. Unfortunately my solution below fires all the animations in sequence without waiting for anything to complete.

```
def Animate_Widget(self,index):
    if index < 10:
        anim = Animation(x = self.position[index][0], y = self.position[index][1], d=1)
        anim.bind(on_complete=self.Animate_Widget(index + 1))
        anim.start(self.ids['widget' + str(index)])

def Resize_Layout(self):
    self.Animate_Widget(0)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that kivy.Animation has inbuilt ways of doing sequential(what you want), repeating and parallel animation. Here is the relevant part of the docs from kivy.org:

http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.animation.html#sequential-animation

Comment: @Totem seems that asker is not trying to create it's own animation. If you see the code, clearly wants to animate 10 widgets in a row based on their index.

Comment: @erm3nda Yes I know. Kivy provides this functionality without the need for callbacks. Look at the link.

Comment: All the content on that link is for 1 widget, to chain multiple effects. Nothing about to animate multiple Widgets in row. I always read links before talk. Tell me which exact function do you think that allow you to Animate few different widgets in a row?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here:

```
anim.bind(on_complete=self.Animate_Widget(index + 1))
```

You call your callback straight away. This is because the arguments to `anim.bind` are evaluated when calling. Instead, define another function or lambda to delay calling that can be called without any arguments:

```
def callback():
    self.Animate_Widget(index + 1)
anim.bind(on_complete=callback)
```

Or:

```
anim.bind(on_complete=lambda: self.Animate_Widget(index + 1))
```

Comment: Thanks for both the fix and explanation!