# Kivy wait for animation to finish before continuing

Tags: python, animation, kivy

How can I wait for kivy Animation to finish before allowing the code that started it to continue? For example, the following method updates the widget position:

```
def update_actor_widget(self, actor):
    final = self._get_screen_pos(actor.location)
    a = Animation(x=final[0], y=final[1], duration=0.5)
    a.start(actor.widget)
```

I do not want it to return (thus possibly allowing other animations to start) before the `actor` actually is where it belongs. Using time.sleep() just hangs the app altogether. Using `Animation.on_complete` does schedule something to happen when the animation is complete, but doesn't block the execution of the function that called animation.

Comment: try to schedule your animations, using the clock object. https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html?highlight=clock

Comment: Thank you. It does not really answer my question in general, but it allows to hack around the problem I had. If you will rewrite your comment as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: i myself wasn't sure if i  fully understood your problem, and just droped it here in case it might help, it's not really an answer. If you managed to implement a solution to your problem using the kivy Clock object please post it as an answer :).

Comment: Well, it turns out I didn't really solve my problems. I have built something like a sequential animation as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623010/using-recursion-with-kivy-on-complete-animation-event  but I still didn't manage to disable the rest of the code until the animation finishes. I've tried to creating a boolean that tracks the state of the animation (setting True in `on_start` and False in `on_complete` and disabling input while it's True), but for some weird reason it stays False even when animation is visibly running.

Comment: if you wan't some piece of code to run after the animation you can schedule it since you know how long the animation is going to take.

Comment: Not really. I want no piece of code to run until it has finished. Or, at least, I want *certain* pieces of code not to run until it has finished.

Comment: For that you may want to use a flag on your object which you can set to track whether an animation is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank everyone for the comments, I finally got it working. It was a bit tricky so in case someone else wants to do something similar here is how I did it (inside main game widget class):

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    # Initializing stuff...
    ...
    self.anim_queue = []
    self.block_keyboard = False

def create_movement_animation(self, widget):
    self.anim_queue.append((widget, Animation(x=widget.expected_x, y=widget.expected_y))
    # Adding widget-animation tuple

def block(self):
    self.block_keyboard = True

def run_animation(self):
    if len(self.anim_queue)>0:
        w, a = self.anim_queue.pop(0)
        a.bind(on_start=lambda x,y: self.block(),
            on_complete=lambda x,y: self.run_animation())
        a.start(w)
    else:
        self.block_keyboard=False

def _on_key_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
    if self.block_keyboard:
        return
    for actor in self.map.actors:
        actor.make_turn()
        if actor.moved:
            self.create_movement_animation(actor.widget)
    self.run_animation()
```

It works as follows: `_on_key_down` calls the gameplay logic code that calculates expected positions for all the widgets. All the widgets that need to move, along with the expected animations, are placed into `self.anim_queue`. `self.run_animation` keeps calling itself via on_complete, setting blocking flag to True along the way, until `self.anim_queue` is exhausted. At which point it sets it to False and quits, allowing the next button to be processed and, thus, the next turn to start.

I have shot my leg a couple of times, so: first, arguments to `on_*` parameters are evaluated during binding, so they have to be wrapped in lambdas to prevent all animations firing off simultaneously. Second, you need to create `actor_moved()` check, otherwise there are empty animations moving widgets from their positions to the exact same positions, in effect freezing the game for num-widgets*duration seconds.